# How do I make collisions, I tried everything I could and this should work, but doesn't?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have this code where I make a ball, and a player used for a soccer game I plan to make:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Soccer</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/3.16.2/phaser.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function preload() {
    this.load.image('player', 'assets/player.png');
    this.load.image("net", "assets/net.png");
    this.load.image("ball", "assets/ball.png");
}

function create() {
  A = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.A);
  S = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.S);
  D = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.D);
  W = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.W);

    this.add.image(config.width - 100, config.height - 120, "net").setScale(0.2, 0.2);
  
    this.ball = this.physics.add.image(config.width / 2, config.height - 50, "ball").setScale(0.1, 0.1);
  
    this.player = this.physics.add.image(config.width / 4, config.height, 'player').setScale(0.1, 0.1);
  
    this.ball.setBounce(1)
    this.player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    this.ball.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
}
function update() {
    this.physics.add.collider(this.ball, this.player);

    let cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    if (D.isDown) {
      this.player.x += 2.5;
    }
    if (A.isDown) {
      this.player.x -= 2.5;
    }
    if (W.isDown) {
      this.player.y -= 2.5;
    }
}

const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: {
                y: 100,
            },
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

It should be creating a player, a ball, and a goal. I want to make it so that the ball and player can collide, but when I run it, the player only collides with the top and bottom of the ball, what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are several things you would have to fix, for the collisions to work.

1. Setup-code should always be put in the `create` function, not in the `update` function *(since the later will be executed 60 times per second)*, so move following lines into the `create` function

   ```
   this.physics.add.collider(this.ball, this.player);
   // although this line is not really needed
   let cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
   ```
2. When using physics you should not move the `gameobject` by setting the `position` property *(or the `x` / `y` properties)*, you have to move the object with the `velocity` for the physics to work.

fixing these few parts, should make the basic collisions work.

**Here a small working demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
      default: 'arcade',
      arcade: {
          gravity: {
              y: 100,
          },
          debug: true
      }
    },
    scene: {
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
}; 

function create() {
    // CREATE IMAGE FOR DEMO -- START
    let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
    graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    graphics.generateTexture('ball', 10, 10);
    graphics.generateTexture('player', 25, 50);
    graphics.generateTexture('net', 30, 30);
    // CREATE IMAGE FOR DEMO -- END
    
    A = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.A);
    S = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.S);
    D = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.D);
    W = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.W);

    this.add.image(config.width - 100, config.height - 120, "net")

    this.ball = this.physics.add.image(config.width / 2, config.height - 50, "ball");
    this.player = this.physics.add.image(config.width / 4, config.height, 'player');

    this.ball.setBounce(1);
    this.player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    this.ball.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

    this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.ball);
}

function update() {

    this.player.setVelocityX(0);
    
    if (D.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityX(50)
    }
    if (A.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityX(-50)
    }
    if (W.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityY(-50)
    }
}


new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```